# SQLite Data to Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method that gets all values in a SQLite table. The application uses SQLite. Now, I want to make these data load in a spinner. How will I do that?

```
public List<Outlet> getAllOutlet(){

    List<Outlet> outletlist = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OUTLET;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Outlet outlet = new Outlet();
            outlet.setOID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            outlet.setOutletname((cursor.getString(2)));
            outlet.setOCode(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding outlet to list
            outletlist.add(outlet);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return outlet list
    return outletlist;
}
```

Comment: first of all: please don't use any `ArrayAdapter`, your data model is sqlite db so use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score -2):

you do that by creating a array adapter as follows

```
// Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> outletNames = new ArrayList<String>;();
    List<Outlet> outlets = getAllOutlet();
    for(Outlet outlet: outlets){
         outletNames.add(outlet.getOutletname);
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, outletNames);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Or if you want better customization with custom views create your own adapter extending ArrayAdapter.
You can also follow this tutorial if you have trouble
[Android populating Spinner data from SQLite database](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/)

Comment: why do you people use `ArrayAdapter` when dealing with sqlite db? it is a mystery that i cannot understand, why not just to use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?